# How to get the file data from access environment variable values without build the new .env file?

Tags: python, environment-variables

First, I export the file path by terminal like `export DB_PASS=/home/Hang/git/pass/password.txt`

MY password.txt:

```
T8#34bc
```

After than, I try to get back the password on my python script.

```
import os

print(os.environ.get(DB_PASS))
```

And it will print the path`/home/Hang/git/pass/password.txt`
How can I get the password without build the new .env file?

Comment: Now that you have got DB_PASS, you can just simply `open(os.environ.get('DB_PASS'), 'r')` and read the file.

Comment: When I used ```print (open(os.environ.get('DB_PASS'), 'r'))``` , I got ```<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/Hang/git/pass/password.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>```

Comment: You didn't put the password in the environment variable.  You put a file name.  So if you want to get the password, you have to open and read that file.

Comment: oh I see. Thank you the solutions.